# What is the current state of Unit testing support in the R language

Tags: unit-testing, r

[R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) is a statistics programming language.  Part of R is the use of Packages, which themselves are written in the R language.  Programming best practice includes the use of unit-testing to test the functions within these packages while they are being written and when they are used.

I am aware of a few packages for unit testing within R, these being

- [RUnit](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RUnit/index.html)
- [Svunit](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svUnit/index.html)
- [Testthat](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/testthat/index.html)

I'm interested to know;

Are there any other packages out there ?
Given peoples experience, do these packages excel at different things ?
What's the current state of the art in unit testing for R ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Unit testing seems to be more or less a solved problem, so all three packages will likely be adequate for your needs.  There are subtle differences between them though:

`RUnit` is based on xunit, and as such is easy to understand if you've used any versions of it from other languages.

`svUnit` uses the same tests as RUnit, but includes a GUI to help with interactive use.

`testthat` isn't compatible with either, but includes much the same features and can check to only execute tests on files that haven't changed, which is useful for testing large projects.

---

*Several years later...*

[`RUnit`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RUnit) and [`svUnit`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svUnit) still don't have checks for messages and warnings, nor test caching, and don't seem to be under much development, so [`testthat`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/testthat/) should be your first choice for new projects.  You can convert `RUnit` tests to `testthat` tests using my [`runittotestthat`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/runittotestthat/) package.

Comment: `svUnit` can also provide output that is understood by the continuous integration tool [Hudson](https://hudson.dev.java.net/).

Comment: There is also now **[unitizer](https://github.com/brodieG/unitizer)**, though still in beta and github only (`devtools::install_github("brodieg/unitizer")`).  It is fairly different to the existing frameworks as it stores test expressions and the resulting objects to allow easy regression checks.

Answer (score 6):

here is a few things I've found from Google.

This topic was discussed on the mailing list [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2009-October/055057.html) which mentioned the packages above.  It seems RUnit and svunit will execute the same test code, but Runit also has tracking and code coverage functions.

A comparison of the two is also on the R wiki at http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=developers:runit

Comment: about the "code coverage" offered by RUnit, do check [this message](https://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_name=474C639E.5080900%40epigenomics.com).  it's from November 2007 but it still stands.

Comment: @mariotomo: that link no longer seems to work.  Any comments or updates?

Comment: better than a direct link, this is the way to find the message. it is in the `runit-help` mailing list of the `runit` project in sourceforge.net. it is by the author of `runit` and timestamped 2007-11-27 18:36. »Having said that please note that the inspect mechanism is not heavily used and tested as it is rather impractical as only one function call at a time can be tracked. This is far from being a code coverage tool.«